# Select Teamcity Linux Agent via System Properties

Tags: linux, teamcity, redhat, agent, suse

I am trying to set-up my build config to run on only specific flavors of Linux Only (Like SLES 10 SP3 or Redhat 5)

Is there an agent requirements property I can use to select specific flavors of Linux like Redhat or SLES 10 or SLES 11 etc?

Currently I only know how to select agents via these properties which is not working well:

Attribute       Linux Example:
System.os.name      Linux
System.os.arch          amd64 / s390x / i386 / etc.
System.os.version   2.6.32.54-0.13.TDC.1.R.1-default, 2.6.27.19-5-default, 2.6.9-42.ELsmp etc.
Any help is greatly appreciated. I do not want to specify the agent name.

I am using TeamCity 7.0. 
I am aware I may need to do something to the agents to make this information available but not sure what that is.

Comment: I would use Agent pools for this type of thing.

Comment: We have pools but they are for regions not OS specific. Every other OS has an attribute for this sort of thing but Linux which I feel is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [build agent configuration file](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Agent+Configuration) `<TeamCity Agent Home>/conf/buildagent.properties` gives you the ability to specify properties that can participate in the Agent requirements expressions.

You'll need to do a little extra work to get it set up, but it will give you what you're looking for.